# python dataframe convert column to row

Tags: python, dataframe

Attempting to convert a single dataframe column into a row.  I've seen multiple responses to similar questions, but most of the questions pertain to multiple columns and rows.  I can't find the simple solution to converting the following:

```
    value
0   A   
1   B  
2   C  
3   D  
4   E  
5   F  
6   G  
7   H  
8   I  
9   J  
10  K  
11  L
```

To

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be a row with N columns... or a space delimited string?

Comment: Are you looking for `transpose`?

Comment: Might be using transpose wrong, but yes ideally that would be it.  I get the following error:  TypeError: transpose() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Can you post how you use `transpose`?

Answer (score 4):

To transpose the `value` dataframe

`value1 = value.transpose()`

Comment: Or, the commonly used `value.T`.

Comment: This is all I needed.  Thanks much!